# how to use recyclerlistview in funtional component

Tags: react-native, recyclerlistview

I want use recyclerlistview in functional component in my app but i am not able to find proper example. any suggestions? My data set is

```
const data =
[
  {
    "key": "11",
    "id": 1,
    "name": "abc"
  },
  {
    "key": "12",
    "id": 2,
    "name": "xyz"
  },
]
```